# Lambda Calculus vs Turing Machine

Tags: automata, lambda-calculus, computation-models

How functional programming using lambda calculus is analogous to construction of Turing machine as per computational aspects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is that every computation describable in lambda calculus can be computed on a turing machine, at the same time every Turing machine program can be converted into a lambda calculus.

The long answer would include proofs that both of those statements are true but that's a bit out of scope for this site.

Comment: That gives me some intuition .Thanks.